# How to reject with new message asynchronous javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning things about promises and I am confused with that function. I need to return a reject with message when connect() is not working. I tried a catch but i need to create reject for entire fucntion pooledDownload(). Please help me.

```html
const pooledDownload = (connect, save, downloadList, maxConcurrency) => {

  for (let i = 0; i < maxConcurrency; i++) {
    connect()
    .then((connection) => {
      const { download, close } = connection;
      download(downloadList[i])
      .then((result) => save(result));
      close();
    })
    .catch(() => {
      throw new Error("connection failed")
    });
  }
}

module.exports = pooledDownload
```

Comment: The function needs to return a promise. Then you can use `reject("connection failed")`. But you'll have a problem if more than one connection fails, because you can only reject a promise once.

Comment: Could you please provide more details?

Comment: BTW  what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `connect()` in a `for` loop, you are creating multiple `Promise`s. If you want to coalesce the results from all the `Promise` objects into one failure, you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).

For example,

```js
const pooledDownload = async (/*...*/) => {
    return Promise.all(
        // create an array of promises by mapping each element of an array of 1..N to a Promise
        [...Array(maxConcurrency).keys()].map(() => {
            return connect().then(/*...*/)
        })
    );
};
```

This will create a `maxConcurrency`-length array of `Promise` objects and pass it to `Promise.all`, which will reject if any of the items in the list reject and resolve if all the items in the list resolve. If you return that result, then your `pooledDownload` function will resolve/reject based on the success of all the individual connections.

###### Additional Note

It looks like your `download` function is also returning a promise. If you want the entire "connect -> download -> save" chain to act like one "unit" and succeed/fail together, then you need to `return download(/*...*/)` from your `then` call. Otherwise, the call to `download()` is creating a new promise that is not "connected to the chain" so to speak. You're also going to need to watch out for when you call `close`, since currently you don't wait for the `download` call to finish before closing.

Since I don't know which functions are async in this case, I can't exactly say how it should look, but this would be pretty close:

```js
const singleDownload = async (connect, save, downloadListItem) => {
    return connect().then((connection) => {
        const { download, close } = connection;
        return download(downloadListItem).then(async (result) => {
            await save(result); // assume save is async
            close();
        });
    });
};

const pooledDownload = async (connect, save, downloadList, maxConcurrency) => {
    const allDownloads = [...Array(maxConcurrency).keys()].map((key) => {
        return singleDownload(connect, save, downloadList[key]);
    });
    return Promise.all(allDownloads);
}
```